# layout not scrolling when added marquee feature to textview

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying add to marquee textview which is at the bottom of the page.I 
have added it but page is not scrollable when i do that. I use this code inside of the Linear Layout. What it's wrong ? Thanks for any help.

Here is the marquee bottom of the page.
https://i.postimg.cc/SQrDzRtq/marque.png

Scroll come back again when i change layout_height, but marquee text move top of the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0691bf"
    tools:context=".AnaEkran">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/arkaplan"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">



        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/maç2back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/maç1back"
                fbutton:srcCompat="@color/boxes" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider8"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/maç3back"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maç3back"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.431" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider9"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/maç4back"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maç4back"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.431" />




            <!-- -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/maç6back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/maç5back"
                fbutton:srcCompat="@color/boxes" />



            .........




        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



    </ScrollView>



    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollingtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25dp" />




    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: are you  trying to design a text that will remain exactly bottom the page and scroll as you scroll ?

Comment: The text need to stay bottom of the page always.So it's need to stay while scrolling or stop.

Answer (score 0):

this code always keeps this TextView at the bottom of the page. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0691bf"
tools:context=".AnaEkran">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/maç2back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/maç1back"
                fbutton:srcCompat="@color/boxes" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider8"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/maç3back"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maç3back"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.431" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider9"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/maç4back"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/maç4back"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.431" />


            <!-- -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/maç6back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/maç5back"
                fbutton:srcCompat="@color/boxes" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollingtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: İt's scrolling but marquee textview gone.